# UK - What role does a cover letter play and can it help in subsequent applications after refusal

Tags: visas, nigerian-citizens

I am a programmer and an employee with a good pay. I was refused a UK standard 6-month visitor visa in January 2018 due to lack of evidence for the funds in my salary account and savings account, and also lack of evidence of my Late dad's inheritance (4,950.30 British Pound was paid into my savings account from the sale of one of my dad's properties).

I earn 514.79 British Pound from my employer..

And I intend to spend 1,100 British Pound for my trip. Accommodation and food will be provided by my British uncle.

I currently have 3,266.55 British Pound in my salary account.

Aside from my job, I develop web applications for my clients and they pay into my salary account, which was stated in my application. I intend to reapply with all invoices of payment and a snapshot of what I designed / developed for each client. My personal company is not registered. I hope this is not an issue.

Secondly, I'm having issues drafting a good cover letter for my application. I would like to understand what role a cover letter plays in the application process. Can a good cover letter help with my future applications?

@Traveller Please find the refusal letter as requested.

** To prove my inheritance: ** I will submit the following documents (1) My dads death cert. (2) MOU of the sells of one of his properties (3) Letter from one of my brother that also benefitted.

[image]

Comment: As I said in your previous questions, you can *state* where payments come from all you wish, but without *evidence* you aren't going to get very far.  A cover letter, no matter how well crafted, isn't going to replace evidence here.

Comment: Thnks for your response @moo    I have invoice of payment, do you think that wont help.

Comment: In all of your questions, you state that you *dont* have invoices or receipts for all payments into your account - so which is it?

Comment: I dont have invoices for lil payments like 9000 Naira (17.89 British Pound) and they are about 5 payments

Comment: @olowogbo You’ve already had one refusal for lack of evidence. If you reapply and the missing invoices are for one or two very small amounts the ECO may accept the situation, but more likely not in view of the previous refusal. A second refusal will make your situation worse and further decrease your chances of any visa in future. Why are you so desperate to go to the UK right now? It would be much better to wait until you can demonstrate a clean financial history before reapplying.

Comment: @Traveller Thank you for your comment. I am not desperate just wish to spend my leave in the UK. I was refused on the 8th of January 2018. I traveled to the UAE on a business trip and an allowance was paid into my account by my company.  I have also been to Israel 2013 ( Jerusalem precisely on Pilgrimage where i spent 8 days). I can upload my refusal if need be. David Richery I was refused UK 6 months family visit visa.

Comment: @olowogbo A salary of £514 and savings of around £3k is not much by UK standards. How much is your flight and how long are you planning on staying - is £1,100 realistic? In my opinion, it is better if an application stacks up by itself without the need for a covering letter - there is space in the application to provide further information, try to utilise just this if you can. If you really feel a cover letter is essential, I would a) limit it to max 1 page; b) use bullet points; c) focus on clarifying the previous refusal reasons.

Comment: @traveller Thank you for your kind response. £514 is about 260,000Naira and above an average pay in Nigeria. As at this moment cheapest Round flight ticket to the UK from  Nigeria is 270,000 Naira (£520). I intend shopping for £560 or less. Please let me know if this is a concern

Comment: @Traveller Can I also post my cover letter here for your review. Thanks

Comment: @olowogbo How long do you plan to stay in the UK? £560 for shopping may seem a lot to you but it could be gone in the blink of an eye depending on what you hope to do and buy. As your accommodation & food will be paid for by your uncle £560 seems ok for a short trip, probably not for anything longer than 1 month. I assume your British uncle can demonstrate his eligibility & ability to sponsor your visit, and you have the paperwork to prove it.

Comment: @Traveller I am so delighted with your swift response, it gives me hope. I have 20 days of leave in a year, I plan to spend two weeks (14days)in the UK. Same days in my previous application.  Please what do you mean by 'eligibility & ability to sponsor your visit, and you have the paperwork to prove it. I will submit his datapage , drivers lience and work ID.

Comment: @olowogbo From the U.K. gov Immigration rules regarding Funds, maintenance and accommodation provided by a third party:
V 4.3 A visitor’s travel, maintenance and accommodation may be provided by a third party where the decision maker is satisfied that they:
(a) have a genuine professional or personal relationship with the visitor; and
(b) are not, or will not be, in breach of UK immigration laws at the time of decision or the visitor’s entry to the UK; and
(c) can and will provide support to the visitor for the intended duration of their stay. (Eg evidenced by uncle’s bank statements)

Comment: @olowogbo Have you read all the guidance available on the U.K. gov web page? For example, the guidance on supporting documents specifically states driving licence should not be supplied. Providing superfluous information / documents will not help your application.

Comment: @Traveller - I don't think my uncle is ready to provide his statement of account. Will this affect my application. Thanks once again

Comment: It can affect the application. If he is offering to help pay for the costs of your trip then he must prove he has enough money to do that.

Comment: @user16259 - your comment is appreciated.  I am paying for my flight tickets and also going with about £550. My trip is x2 of my Salary and my balance is x6 of my trip.

Answer (score 2):

It is better if an application stacks up by itself without the need for a covering letter - there is space in the application to provide further information, try to utilise just this if you can. If you really feel a cover letter is essential, I would a) limit it to max 1 page; b) use bullet points; c) focus on clarifying the previous refusal reasons. You could use a cover letter to explain your uncle’s situation, however, in my opinion, without evidence to show he can provide the promised accommodation and food your application is very likely to be refused. Taking into account that Nigeria is considered a high risk country by the U.K. if I were you I would postpone my application until I could meet the criteria in my own right.

Comment: I stated I will stay with him in my previous application. Is it right to book a hotel in my next application? He was interviewed by the Home Office and was also acknowledged, Staying with him was not a concern in the refusal letter.

Comment: @olowogbo Ok, well looks like that shouldn’t be a problem then. Why book a hotel (which anyway isn’t a pre requisite for a U.K. visa) when you plan to stay with your uncle? Can you show you can reasonably afford UK hotel costs? I fear you’re over-complicating this - address the reason for the original refusal as a priority and keep the rest of your application as simple and clear as possible, ensuring that you’ve covered off each aspect of the requirements in the light of your specific situation. I’m not sure ‘acknowledged’ means ‘accepted’, particularly as they had another reason to refuse.

Comment: Now I am scared. Can I paste the refusal letter here for your review?

Comment: @olowogbo Yes, please post the refusal with personal details redacted (probably should have done that when you first posted your question).

Comment: Please find the refusal letter as requested. I await your review

Comment: @olowogbo From the lack of comment by the ECO you could infer that your sponsor was acceptable. Whether that’s 100% reliable I can’t be sure, all I’d say is that when I’ve sponsored applications I have provided evidence of my ability to meet the commitment. Since you’ve already had one refusal in my opinion it would be better not to leave any potential gaps.

Comment: Thank you for your review. Again, Can this documents effectively trash ECO's concern on my inheritance.  (1) My dads death cert. (2) MOU of the sells of one of his properties (3) Letter from one of my brother that also benefitted.

Comment: i just notice that the third bullet point of my refusal ** An interview with your sponsor ** was highlighted, is this a concern?

Comment: @olowogbo What is a MOU? I wouldn’t bother with the letter from your brother, in my opinion. Highlighted by whom?

Comment: Memorandum of Understanding between both parties. Highlighted by the ECO. Kindly see the attached letter

Comment: @olowogbo It would be preferable to provide the legally enforceable contract for the sale and ownership transfer of your father’s property.

Comment: Memorandum of Understanding should suffice. It contains agreement and signature of all the beneficiaries

Comment: How have you been?. Please, can I post my cover letter here for your review?

Comment: Your attention is needed

Comment: Will just 2 pics of me and my Unlce suffice? since we don't bear the same surname.

Comment: @olowogbo Have you read the guidance on supporting documents? On page7 it specifically states that you should not provide photographs (other than the photos of the applicant) https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

Comment: Please, can I post my cover letter here for your review?

Comment: @olowogbo The rules of this forum preclude discussion-based questions https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask so I’m not sure that uploading your proposed cover letter is allowed. However in this 1 instance if you want to do it I will take a look and briefly point out any obvious faults, if there are any.

Comment: I can post and delete after your review. But i would like to know when you will be available

Comment: Someone noticed the highlighting on AN INTERVIEW WITH YOUR SPONSOR on my refusal letter.

Does this indicate an issue or its normal?